# Can't add rows to DataGridView after adding the first one

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

I have this code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.KeyChar == 13) {
           db database = new db();
           database.set_connection(Properties.Settings.Default.connection);
           DataTable result = database.search(textBox1.Text, "", "");
           if (result.Rows.Count == 0)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("nothing found", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
               textBox1.SelectAll();
               textBox1.Focus();
           }
           else {
               if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
               {
                   DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                   row.Cells[0].Value = result.Rows[0]["title"].ToString();
                   row.Cells[1].Value = result.Rows[0]["code"].ToString();
                   row.Cells[2].Value = result.Rows[0]["sell"].ToString();
                   row.Cells[3].Value = "1";
                   row.Cells[4].Value = "";
                   decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(result.Rows[0]["sell"].ToString()) * 1;
                   row.Cells[5].Value = total;

               }
               else {
                   bool found = false;
                   int position = 0;
                   foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in dataGridView1.Rows)
                   {
                       if (ro.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == result.Rows[0]["title"].ToString())
                       {
                           found = true;
                           position = ro.Index;
                           break;
                       }
                   }

                   if (found)
                   {
                       dataGridView1.Rows[position].Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[position].Cells[3].Value) + 1;
                       decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[position].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[position].Cells[3].Value);
                       dataGridView1.Rows[position].Cells[5].Value = total;
                   }
                   else {
                       DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                       dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                       row.Cells[0].Value = result.Rows[0]["title"].ToString();
                       row.Cells[1].Value = result.Rows[0]["code"].ToString();
                       row.Cells[2].Value = result.Rows[0]["sell"].ToString();
                       row.Cells[3].Value = "1";
                       row.Cells[4].Value = "";
                       decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(result.Rows[0]["sell"].ToString()) * 1;
                       row.Cells[5].Value = total;
                   }



               }



           }
       }
    }
```

When I run my app I can add the first row without any problems but when I want to add a second row, I got this error :

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: rowIndex
```

What is the problem??

EDIT:

the error is happening in:

```
+       row.Cells[0].Value  'row.Cells[0].Value' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'    object {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}
```

EDIT 2:

This is my full new code after rewriting some parts but I am still having the same problem

Comment: What line exactly are you going outside of the bounds of the array?  If you are running your program through Visual Studio it will break at the problem spot.

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying a collection while you iterate over it..bad idea.  Instead of adding the rows to the `DataGridView` in the loop, just create a list and store each row in the list and add them to the `DataGridView`after you exit the loop.

Also, whatever `result` is, you need to make sure that it is not empty before trying to index it's contents.

Comment: I looping throw rows only to check for duplicates rows so I can update the quantity field

Answer (score 0):

Run in debugger and enable exceptions in `Debug -> Exceptions -> CLR Exceptions` and see where it will crash.

I just can assume that a problem in `result.Rows[0],` you haven't checked whether `Rows != null and Rows.Count() > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You have several instances of result.row[0] in your else clause, i dont see where you are declaring 'result' so this is probably the source if not the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding rows to a table while looping through the rows seems like a poor way to go about it. Perhaps that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the current row to the last added row and currentcell on every loop
something like

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```

then set the currentcell 
something like this

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
```