# Cannot add a row the second time via mouse clicks

Tags: datagridview

I am dealing with an unbound DataGridView control.  It is working quite well in most ways but I have one problem:
I cannot add a second row via the UI after adding the first row (this is different from [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765610/cant-add-rows-to-datagridview-after-adding-the-first-one) in which the author was adding rows programmatically).   I have placed `Console.Writeline()` statements (I am developing a control in a test app) and have noticed that at the same time that I cannot get a response trying to add a row the second time, I also no longer get `RowValidating` and other events.  It is like all the events have been disabled.   I can still edit cells of existing rows, I just cannot add a row the second time.

I have searched for information on this but have come up empty--hence this post.  BTW, I am using .NET 3.5 and cannot use .NET 4.0 for external compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. It was a misconfiguration of the DataGridView.  In particular, it was setting the Row Template attribute `ReadOnly` to true.   This attribute affects added rows to the grid thus only the rows added were read-only and thus could not be changed to add more rows.  Once I set that to "false" (as in the screenshot), it all worked.

[image]